# Is it possible to visibility of an element based on its position in page with XSL:FO?

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

Is there a way to set element visibility based on its positioning within a page using XSL:FO. Specifically I'm looking to generate a horizontal rule following the end of the paragraph unless that rule is the last element of the main page body (as in not footer, etc)

I don't have any ideas here... Is this possible with markers? I'm using Apache FOP for rendering.

Comment: I am not sure whether there is an XSL-FO way, these days CSS has pseudo class selectors like `:last-child` or `:last-of-type`, I don't think these have found their way into similar standardized FO attributes. You have tagged your question as xslt as well, however, so you might have ways to ensure that XSLT only outputs a ruler as long as it is not the last item processed that maps to body child, using e.g. `position()` or `xsl:number` to find the input position and make sure you output the ruler only if it is not last.

Comment: FWIW, I've done similar with Antenna House Formatter: https://www.balisage.net/Proceedings/vol26/html/Graham01/BalisageVol26-Graham01.html#d608503e400. I don't know how you'd do it with FOP. I also don't know how you'd do it with markers without needing two formatting passes because I expect that the vertical position of each rule would be different on different pages.

Comment: You could draw rules under all paragraphs. Then process to the formatting tree result and check the position of the last one on the page and it nothing following it that isn't footer material then remove it and output the tree to your desired format.

Comment: If FOP supported `border-collaps="collapse-with-precedence"` and the lines were just lines, then it could be done with every paragraph being a single-cell table row with a bottom border and with a higher-precedence `border="hidden"` on, say, the `fo:table`.